# Protecting allocated memory

Tags: c, memory, malloc, mprotect

I need to allocate dynamically some portions of memory, each with some protection - either RW or RX.

I tried to allocate memory by `malloc`, but `mprotect` always returns `-1 Invalid argument`.

My sample code:

```
void *x = malloc(getpagesize());
mprotect(x, getpagesize(), PROT_READ); // returns -1, it;s sample, so only R, not RW or RX
```

Comment: what is the ``errno`` you got? If -1 is return, then ``errno`` will be set accordingly. [Here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect) is the man page.

Comment: @gongzhitaao 22: EINVAL

Comment: Well, according to man page, EINVAL means "addr is not a valid pointer, or not a multiple of the system page size.".  `malloc` doesn't guarantee alignment, you should use something like `posix_memalign`.

Comment: marking a malloc'd allocation as READONLY will also mark all other bits of memory on the same page as READONLY, which is likely to confuse the bits of your program and the runtime that might have heap allocations living there when they try to write to memory they've legitimately malloc'd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to allocate a page of memory, the correct choice is probably to use `mmap()`

```
void *x = mmap(NULL, getpagesize(), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
```

Note that since you pass the permissions into the call, you really don't need to use `mprotect()` afterward. You can use it, however, to change the permissions later, of course, like if you want to load some data into the page before making it read only.  You can later free it using `munmap()`.

Since this is an anonymous map, no backing file is used, so it behaves much like `malloc()` would in that sense.

Answer (score 5):

> mprotect()  changes protection for the calling process's memory
>   page(s) containing any part of the address range in the interval
>   [addr, addr+len-1].  addr
>          must be aligned to a page boundary

The last part here is important. malloc might not give you page aligned memory just because you request the size of a page, so you either have to allocate a suitable chunk of memory and align it, or allocate page aligned memory using e.g. [posix_memalign](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html)()

You should also inspect errno if mprotect() fails, as to learn more about why it fails.

Comment: about memalign: `It is recommended that new code not use this function and it is further recommended that its use in older code be reconsidered. It is only included to allow older code to recompile. The UNIX 98 specification does not have this function. Most modern operating systems memory allocation routines return aligned memory.`

Comment: @Ari The last part is not relevant in this regard, while memory allocation routines return aligned memory, they do not return page aligned memory. Anyway, I changed it to the modern variant, posix_memalign